# Communicate directly between browser and java application with url of the application?

Tags: java, url, cross-browser

I am trying to create a communication between browser and my java application.

Basically what I have in mind is after certain operation is done in the browser, the browser will go to certain `URL` address of my application like `http://myapp:1212?code=12345` and it will send the code to my application and later the application will print the received code.

Is it possible for creating the `URL` address as stated above so that my application will recognize it?

Related question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/272019/communicating-between-browser-and-a-native-application-securely?newreg=c65543f1f7624e29b461303c72c6264d 
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/253338/how-do-i-what-is-the-best-way-to-interact-with-a-desktop-application-from-a-br

Comment: So you are saying the browser should hit the `URL` of your application by itself  after certain operation is done?

Comment: @PrakashThete yes it is